Creating an appointment on Outlook and attaching a Teams meeting link using Outlook Object Model
I'm trying to create an appointment on Outlook using the Outlook Object Model available in C#. I can't find out how to attach a link to a Teams meeting along with the appointment.
Here is what I have, I can't figure out how to generate a meeting link to attach it in the body.
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

Outlook.Folder calendarFolder = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;

Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment = calendarFolder.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

newAppointment.Subject = ...;
newAppointment.Start = ...;
newAppointment.End = ...;
newAppointment.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
newAppointment.Body = ...;

// Add attendees to the appointment
Outlook.Recipients recipients = newAppointment.Recipients;
recipients.Add("...");
recipients.Add("...");
recipients.Add("...");

newAppointment.Save();
newAppointment.Send();


Outlook knows very little about Teams - Teams functionality in Outlook is implemented through the Teams COM addin.
You can create a Teams meeting using Graph and embed a link in the appointment body: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I wish I could use the Graph API, but I can't because I don't have permission to register apps on Azure in my organization. I started using the Object Model based on your suggestion in the other question
Please tell me if you know another way, and thanks for your help so far!

OOM will let you create an appointment in the Calendar folder, but it won't let you do anything with Graph, even though Outlook might be using it internally. You can use Detours to patch WinHTTP functions and extract the Graph access token, but that is far from being documented or encouraged by Microsoft.
